# Retrofit2 How to get redirect url @HEAD("/")

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a minified URL and I want to have the final URL

With Retrofit 1.9 I used to do this :

```
@HEAD("/XXXXXXXXX")
void fetchFinalUrl(Callback<String> cb);


public void getUrl() {
   mMinifyService.fetchFinalUrl(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void success(String s, Response response) {
                    response.getUrl();
                }
                [...]
}
```

But now with Retrofit 2 .getUrl() not exist any ideas how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Finally got it!

```
public class ApiProvider<T> {

    private Retrofit retrofit;
    private static final String END_POINT_MINIFY = "XXXXXXX";

    public ApiProvider() {
        initAdapter();
    }

    public T getService(Class<T> service) {
        return retrofit.create(service);
    }

    private void initAdapter() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .followRedirects(false)
                .build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(END_POINT_MINIFY)
                .addConverterFactory(new ToStringConverterFactory())
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }

}

public interface IMinifyService {
    @HEAD("/XXXXXXXXX")
    Call<Void> fetchFinalUrl(Callback<String> cb);
}


public class MinifyServiceImpl {

    private ApiProvider<IMinifyService> mApiProvider = new ApiProvider<>();
    private IMinifyService mMinifyService = mApiProvider.getService(IMinifyService.class);

    public Promiser<String, Integer> fetchMinifyUrl() {
        return new Promiser<>((resolve, reject) -> mMinifyService.fetchMinifyUrl().enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
                if (response.code() >= 300 && response.code() < 400){
                    resole.run(response.headers().get("Location"));
                } else {
                    reject.run(response.code());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
                reject.run(t.hashCode());
            }
        }));
    }

}
```

if you want to use Promizer --> [Click here](https://github.com/NodensN/android-promiser)

Answer (score 4):

```
response.raw().request().url()
```

Comment: When I do this I have the minified url and not the final url :/

Comment: response.raw().request().url() gives HttpUrl object. How to extract that url in String format?

Comment: @FerozKhan  just using `toString()`